# String.Right Function Run-time error '424': Object required

Tags: vba, excel

The following line is causing an error that I can't seem to debug. The error says" Object required" and from what I can tell I provided the function and all methods with the proper objects.

The variable "first" is initialized as a string, and this line is within a For loop hence the use of the "i" variable.

```
first = Right(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text, Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Text.LastIndexOf(" "))
```

Comment: Check that "i" is greater than zero and that there is a sheet named "Sheet1" in the active workbook (which is not necessarily the workbook that the macro is in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.Text` returns a `String` and `String` doesn't have a `LastIndexOf` property. In fact, it doesn't have any properties because it's not an object. That's why you get "Object required". What you want is

```
InStrRev(someString, " ")
```

The `InStr` function gives you the index of the first occurrence of the search string while `InStrRev` gives you the last. So this would solve your immediate problem:

```
Dim cellCont As String
'...
cellCont = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value2 'use value or value2, not text
first = Right(cellCont, InStrRev(cellCont, " "))
```

However you probably want the part right of the last space character, so you would need the length of the right part of the string but `InStrRev` will give you the length of the left part. So you have to subtract the position of the space from the total length.

```
first = Right(cellCont, Len(cellCont) - InStrRev(cellCont, " "))
```

---

Another option would be the `Split` function that returns an array:

```
first = Split(cellCont, " ")(UBound(Split(cellCont, " ")))
```

If you knew the number of words beforehand this would look much prettier like

```
first = Split(cellCont, " ")(2)
```

---

Edit: Why you should use `Value` (or `Value2`) instead of `.Text`: `.Text` returns the text that is actually displayed. So if your cell contains a number that is too large for the column it will return `####` for example.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I've been Using '.Text' a fair amount, now I know why it's causing all these issues.

Comment: @slightly_toasted Most of the time it won't cause an issue. If there is text inside the cell it won't be replaced by `####` and `.Text` will be the same as `.Value` as far as I know. It makes a difference mostly with number format and errors.